# excel: remove number from plot, set no number in formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a log formular that prints out errors for values below 0.
I could set these 0 in the formula, but actually I want to have no number, not even 0 inserted. How do I set up a cell/formula with no number?

This is my current formula

```
=WENN(B2>0;LOG10(B2);)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the following

```
=IF(B2>0;LOG10(B2);NV())
```

Here is an explanation: http://office.microsoft.com/de-de/excel-help/nv-funktion-HA102752925.aspx, however I could not find out how to get the according english site.

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(B2>0, log10(B2),"")
```

Hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: No, that makes no difference.

Comment: ... I don't understand... That will definitely give you a blank cell... Maybe I'm not understanding your question correctly then

Comment: The blank cell is not what I want, I want the cell (whatever its value) not to be part of the plot. Similar to NaN values in matlab (not a number). Excel has the same as a function as 'not a value'. I just had forgotten its name.